# how to calculate difference between 2 fields in 2 different tables using a single query?

Tags: sql, select

```
Table Users : user_id , credits_available
Table Survey : user_id, survey_id, credits_required
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between credits_available and credits_required for a particular user_id and specified survey_id ? Is it possible to write a single query instead of calculating separately by 2 different queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL lets you use normal math...

```
SELECT (survey.credits_required - users.credits_available) as endResult
FROM users,survey 
WHERE users.user_id = survey.user_id 
AND survey_id = $surveyID
AND users.user_id = $userID
```

And of course, `$surveyID` is a variable which lists the survey ID in question... `$userID` is a variable which lists the user ID in question...

Comment: this query gives me the rows for all the users .. but i want only for a particular user .. should i use left join or something else?

Comment: @rkt, you could alternatively specifically call out `JOIN survey ON users.user_id = survey.user_id` , but it's essentially the same thing going on.

Answer (score 3):

```
select credits_required - credits_available
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where survey_id = survey_id_parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.user_id,b.survey_id, (b.credits_required - a.credits_available) as credit_difference from Users a, Survey b where a.user_id = b.user_id and b.Survey_ID = {id parameter}
```

Even Better create a stored procedure

```
create procedure getDifference
@SurveyID int,
@UserID int
AS
SELECT a.user_id, b.survey_id,
       (b.credits_required - a.credits_available) as credit_difference
FROM Users a, Survey b
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id and b.Survey_ID = @SurveyID and a.User_id = @UserID
```

To execute it

```
exec getDifference {put your survey id here}, {user id here}
```